# Ruby smarter_csv header issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, smartercsv

I am trying to create a Ruby file that extracts data. I seem to run into an issue as the provided CSV files don't have headers attached. So, I am trying to tell smarter_csv that there are NO headers. The code, I use for this is:

```
transactions = SmarterCSV.process(file, {chunk_size: 20,remove_empty_values: false, remove_zero_values: false, headers_in_file: false, user_provided_headers:{timestamp: :timestamp, location: :loc, lat: :lat, long: :long, rfid: :rfid, start: :tart, ending: :end, type: :type , amount: :amount, status: :status}})
```

I also, add some new headers so they map right. The result unfortunately is an error, which is

> /gems/smarter_csv-1.0.19/lib/smarter_csv/smarter_csv.rb:64:in `process': undefined method`map!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I thought there might be something wrong with the passing of "false", so I changed it to a String, but that resulted unfortunately in that there were no custom headers added. I was wondering if anyone else is struggling with the headers in CSV. Maybe there is an easy solution, or maybe we need to contribute to the GEM. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I also, add some new headers so they map right.
>
> ```
> user_provided_headers:{timestamp: :timestamp, location: :loc, lat: :lat, long: :long, rfid: :rfid, start: :tart, ending: :end, type: :type , amount: :amount, status: :status}
> ```

`:user_provided_headers` [is supposed to be an Array](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) not a Hash:

> user provided Array of header strings or symbols, to define
>   what headers should be used, overriding any in-file headers.
>   You can not combine the :user_provided_headers and :key_mapping
>   options.

...

> the provided CSV files don't have headers attached

If the csv file has no headers, the following makes no sense:

```
location: :loc
```

What would `:location` refer to?  That seems to be saying that the header called `:location` in the file should be called `:loc` in the output.  `smarter_csv`has a setting for mapping existing headers in a file to new names in the output:

> :key_mapping  -- hash which maps headers from the CSV file to keys in
>   the result hash

But you claim your csv file has no headers, and you are also telling smarter_csv that your file has no headers: `headers_in_file: false`.

Here are some examples of how things work:

csv.csv:

```
0,1,2
3,,5
```

And some code:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process(
  'csv.csv',
  {
    headers_in_file: false,
    user_provided_headers: %i[x y z],
    remove_empty_values: false,
    remove_zero_values: false,
  }
)

p data

--output:--
[{:x=>0, :y=>1, :z=>2}, {:x=>3, :y=>"", :z=>5}]
```

If you tell smarter_csv that your file doesn't contain headers with `headers_in_file: false`, and then you provide a `:key_mapping`, which tells smarter csv to map the headers in the file to new names in the output, then you will get an error:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process(
  'csv.csv',
  {
    headers_in_file: false,
    key_mapping: {'x' => 'x_val', 'y' => 'y_val', 'z' => 'z_val'},
    remove_empty_values: false,
    remove_zero_values: false,
  }
)

p data

--output:--
/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/smarter_csv-1.0.19/lib/smarter_csv/smarter_csv.rb:64:in `process': undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from 1.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Now, if your csv file actually contains headers, `headers_in_file: true`, then providing a `:key_mapping` option makes sense:

csv.csv:

```
x,y,z
0,1,2
3,,5
```

The code:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process(
  'csv.csv',
  {
    headers_in_file: true,
    key_mapping: {x: 'x_val', y: 'y_val', z: 'z_val'},  #keys must be symbols
    remove_empty_values: false,
    remove_zero_values: false,
  }
)

p data

--output:--
[{:x_val=>0, :y_val=>1, :z_val=>2}, {:x_val=>3, :y_val=>"", :z_val=>5}]
```

Based on your current understanding of smarter_csv, I suggest you reconsider whether you should be using the `:chunk_size` option.  If you don't know, don't.

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful! I appreciate your quick reply. My issue indeed was passing a HASH instead of an Array. Wasn't really awake with this, but it is good to realize you need to do Array with no headers and a Hash with headers...

Comment: yes, Array needs to be provided with :user_defined_headers option